# Trying to swap the title attribute of a paragraph with the content of the paragraph

Tags: javascript, dom

For example I want to change the HTML like so :

```
<p title="Title text">Content text</p>
```

into this:

```
<p title="Content text">Title text</p>
```

so far I have this code which will make the `title` value equal to what is in `<p>`

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);

function init(){

var b = document.querySelector("p");
b.setAttribute("title",b.textContent);

console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: Certainly you'll need to retrieve the current title before overwriting it. So use `getAttribute()` and store it to a temporary variable, and use that variable to set the `.textContent` after the attribute has been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap them using a variable which holds the value while updating

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init);

function init() {
  var b = document.querySelector("p");
  var temp = b.textContent;
  b.textContent = b.getAttribute("title");
  b.setAttribute("title", temp);
  console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<p title="Title text">Content text</p>
```